# Use of PropertyName to source fill color from database table

Tags: geoserver, sld, propertyname

We use QGIS to style spatial objects, then copy in to GeoServer.

Generally this works well.

However, we can't get GeoServer to source polygon fill colors from a column in a table.

Here is the relevant section of the SLD we are using.

```
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill"><ogc:PropertyName>display_rgb</ogc:PropertyName></se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
         <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

Can anyone tell me why the fill color is not being picked up from the **display_rgb** database table column?

In addition, why does the GeoServer SLD documentation talk about CssParameter and not SvgParameter?

Comment: CssParameters are part of SLD and SvgParameters are used in SE (sld 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

SLD is correct, just applied it incorrectly to layer.
Set it only as an Additional Style and not applied it to the Default Style.